# Using statement to create then destroy buttons in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, using

I want to create and then destroy buttons, all with code, but can't find anything that adequately explains the process.

```
Button btnQA1 = new Button();
greg.Children.Add(btnQA1);
btnQA1.Content = QA;
Grid.SetColumn(btnQA1, CRNOne);
```

How do I put that code above into a using statement? greg is the name of the grid I'm using.

Comment: You cannot destroy the button while the Grid is using it. It's the responsibility of the grid to dispose of its children, just like any other containers.

Comment: That worked. Wanna put your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot destroy the button while the Grid is using it. It's the responsibility of the grid to dispose of its children, just like any other containers